# Can I write my Android App in Cordova and later add more functions to it in Java?

Tags: java, android, ios, cordova

Can I write my App in Cordova and afterwards add some additional functions like Soundrecognation with "pocketsphinx", which is in Java, for Android? 
And also the same for iOS - write the main app in Cordova, add "OpenEars toolkit" support to my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Less short answer:  If there isn't a plugin already available that wraps the APIs that is compatible with Cordova then you'll need to [create one yourself](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide).